# How can I add the current date in ORACLE SQL column?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I add the "now" date in a column? I want to achieve the following scenario: if I insert a row today the date column will have the value 25/10/2021 and if tomorrow I'll execute a SELECT statement, I want to see that column updated with the value 26/10/2021 and so on. Is there a way to keep the column updated without me doing anything manually? Thanks.

Later edit: I want to use that column for a PERIOD in a temporal table. Example: PERIOD FOR example_period(some_date, now_date)

Comment: But as Littlefoot sais in their answer. If it shall show the current date whenever you run a query, why don't you just display `sysdate` (or `trunc(sysdate)` for the date only)? Why store a value that must change every day at midnight? **That doesn't seem to make sense.**

Comment: I know, but this is the request that I got. Let's say I have the record: Name: a Salary: 123 StartDate: 10-10-2020 EndDate: now and then I want to update the salary such that I'll have 2 record for the same person: Name: a Salary: 123 StartDate: 10-10-2020 EndDate: 25-10-2021; Name: a Salary: 123 StartDate: 25-10-2021 EndDate: now

Comment: Then write a view or add a computed column that uses `sysdate`.

Comment: I edited my previous answear. What is a computed column? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Okay with your altered comment this sounds different from what you said so far. You want to split the row into two? In what situation?

Comment: Exactly, I want to keep some sort of history.

Comment: Let me see, if I guess right: Employee #50 got hired 2000-01-01 and got 1000$. So you have a row with 50|1000|2000-01-01|---. Then their salary is raised on 2010-12-24 and they earn now 1200$. Now in your database you want to add a new row 50|1200|2010-12-24|--- and change the old row to 50|1000|2000-01-01|2010-12-23. Yes?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: _"I know, but this is the request that I got. "_  So did you explain to the 'requestor' why it doesn't make sense? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your request comments you have altered your request fundamentally.

One problem: You have an open date range, with a beginning date and an ending date. But when displaying this, you want to substitute the no end" with the current date. This is usually done by storing null (no value) for the date. In a query you can then use `COALESCE` to replace that with the current date:

```
SELECT
  empno,
  salary,
  start_date AS first_day,
  COALESCE(end_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) AS last_day
FROM salaries;
```

And for convenience you can make this a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_salaries AS SELECT <above query>
```

Another problem is that you want this null to change when a newer salary information gets added.

Manually you would just

```
INSERT INTO salaries (empno, salary, start_date, end_date)
VALUES(50, 1200, TRUNC(SYDATE), NULL);

UPDATE salaries SET end_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
WHERE empno = 50 AND end_date IS NULL;
```

If you want this update to happen automatically, there are mainly two options:

1. write a procedure for a new salary that does the insert and update
2. write a trigger to perform the update

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make any sense. It is as if you'd just

```
select empno, ename,
  sysdate                     --> this
from employees
```

every time.

`SELECT` won't update any column value, so ... why would you store such a date in the first place, if you want to keep it synchronized with `sysdate`?

---

But, if you want Oracle to insert `sysdate` into that column as its default value, you'd then create column as such, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id      number,
  3     datum   date default sysdate
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 25.10.2021 14:05:02

SQL>
```

But, it would remain the same "forever", unless you actually `update` its value.

Comment: I want to use that column for a PERIOD. For example: PERIOD FOR example_period(some_date, now_date)

Comment: What is PERIOD FOR? How would you use it? What is SOME_DATE?

Comment: PERIOD FOR statement is used for temporal tables. some_date is just a past date, that I'll set.

Comment: Let's say I have the record: Name: a Salary: 123 StartDate: 10-10-2020 EndDate: now and then I want to update the salary such that I'll have 2 record for the same person: Name: a Salary: 123 StartDate: 10-10-2020 EndDate: 25-10-2021; Name: a Salary: 123 StartDate: 25-10-2021 EndDate: now

Comment: Aha. It is about temporal validity (https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/temporal-validity-12cr1#as-of-period-for-queries). The way you described it in your last comment, I don't think that it should be used that way. You'd have to **a)** update existing row so that you'd insert END_DATE value, **b)** insert a new row which shows person's new salary, the one which is valid from "now" onward.

Answer (score 0):

Add a trigger that fill a column with sysdate :

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_FILL_DATE
BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.MY_DATE_COLUMN IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT sysdate INTO :NEW.MY_DATE_COLUMN FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Or as suggested use 'DEFAULT sysdate' on your column.

Comment: Ummm ... no, don't use a trigger for such a purpose. Set column's **DEFAULT** value instead.

Comment: Indeed. Easier to add a default.

Comment: Not only easier; database would *suffer* if it had to fire that trigger in a bulk insert operation that inserts 10 million rows whose my_date_column is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generated column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE salaries (
  id               NUMBER(10,0)
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                   CONSTRAINT salaries__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_id           CONSTRAINT salaries__emp_id__fk REFERENCES employees (id)
                   NOT NULL,
  salary           NUMBER(12,2)
                   NOT NULL,
  start_date       DATE
                   NOT NULL,
  end_date         DATE
                   NULL,
  assumed_end_date DATE
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_or_now(end_date))
                   NOT NULL
);
```

and create the `DETERMINISTIC` function (in a slight abuse of how it is supposed to be used):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION date_or_now (dt IN DATE) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN COALESCE(dt, SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

Then if you:

```sql
INSERT INTO salaries (emp_id, salary, start_date)
VALUES (1, 123, DATE '2021-01-01');
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   salaries;
```

The output is:

> | ID | EMP_ID | SALARY | START_DATE | END_DATE | ASSUMED_END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |  | 2021-10-25 13:28:08 |

Then if you do:

```sql
UPDATE salaries
SET    END_DATE = DATE '2021-10-01'
WHERE  id = 1;

INSERT INTO salaries (emp_id, salary, start_date)
VALUES (1, 234, DATE '2021-10-01');
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   salaries;
```

The output is:

> | ID | EMP_ID | SALARY | START_DATE | END_DATE | ASSUMED_END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 1 | 234 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 |  | 2021-10-25 13:28:08 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74ccef27a703960892f10dc9ae3fa5ee)*